# Finite dimensionality of a subspace

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $c>0$ and let $Y$ be the space of all distributions of compact support in $(-1,1)$ with singular support at $\{0\}$. Let $X$ be **subspace** of $Y$ such that for any $\phi \in X$ there holds:
$$ \int_{t^2>r^2} \phi'(t)^2\,dt \leq c\,\int_{t^2>r^2-r^4} \phi(t)^2\,dt \quad \forall\, r\in (0,1).$$
Is it true that $X$ must be finite dimensional?

Comment: If $\phi$ is a distribution, how are the displayed integrals defined? Also, what do you mean by "of compact support in $(-1,1)$ with singular support at $\{0\}$", and what role can the "singular support at $\{0\}$" possibly play in the displayed inequality, involving only values of $\phi(t)$ for $t$ away from $0$?

Comment: Also, by "Let $X$ be **subspace** of $Y$ such that for any $\phi \in X$ there holds", do you mean "Let $X$ be the subspace of $Y$ consisting of all $\phi \in Y$ such that the following holds"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis 1) The integrals are taken over the sets of regular points, where $\varphi$ is an ordinary function (perhaps, even $C^\infty$). 2) No, the meaning is as written: we take *some* linear subspace of $Y$ with the described property and ask if it can be infinite-dimensional. 3) There should be a straightforward counterexample, but it is too late here for me to check the details.

Comment: @fedja : Is 1) your guess, or how did you figure that out? And, if that is so, why mention distributions at all?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Singular point of a distribution is usually defined as the point in no neighborhood of which $\varphi$ is a (nice) function (how nice may depend of the context). Not every function with a singularity at $0$ can be extended to a distribution.

Comment: @fedja : I think a singular point is not the same as singular support. Anyhow, again, if your point 1) was meant by the OP, then why mention distributions at all? Also, why mention the "support" at $\{0\}$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Singular support is just the set of singular points. The distributions are mentioned because, as I said, not every function on $(-1,1)\setminus \{0\}$ extends to a distribution on $\mathbb R$, so that requirement imposes a non-trivial restriction. "Singular support  at $\{0\}$" means exactly that every other point is regular (if the OP uses the standard language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta$The answer is no. E.g., let $X$ be the linear span of the set $\{\de,\de',\de'',\dots\}$, where $\de$ is the Dirac delta distribution supported on $\{0\}$. Then $X$ satisfies your condition but is infinite dimensional.

Comment: The one comment about this example is that the restrictions of X away from the origin is finite dimensional. Maybe that should have been my question so as to make this kind of counter example not possible.